# How to use FileUpload in UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, updatepanel

I know that such question was has been many times already but I couldn't find any right solution for my problem.

I have MasterPage1 with ScriptManager. There is MasterPage2 in it. In 2-nd MasterPage I placed Control with UpdatePanel. In this UP I placed FileUpload and SubmitButton:

Master1(with SM) <= Master2 <= Control(with FU and But)

I tried to debug method But_OnClick and saw that FU.PostedFile == null.

I tried to place PostBackTrigger to But in UP, I tried to do it from Control's code behind using something like Page.Master.Master.FindControl("ScriptManager") and it doesn't work.

And I even tried to use AjaxControlToolkit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve this problem by myself!

First of all:

```
<form id="mainForm" runat="server" name="mainForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Then I use AjaxToolkitControl:

```
<ajax:AsyncFileUpload runat="server" ID="upload" OnUploadedComplete="UploadComplete" />
```

And In server event handler **UploadComplete** I can place the file-saving logic. Bingo!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a FileUpload asynchronously.

Have a look at [this control](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/asyncfileupload/asyncfileupload.aspx) which should do what you need.